# Creating serial number based on occurrences in string list and then pairing

Tags: python, list, find-occurrences

I am trying to create list of identification numbers, based on a list of strings. The id numbers will be a combination of the string and a consecutive number.

A short example of what my input list would look like:

```
['N10','N10','N20','N30','N40','N40','N40','N40','N40','N20']
```

I would like to then generate a new list based on the name + a consecutive number, there can be no repetitions in this list. Like this:

```
['N100','N101','N200','N300','N400','N401','N402','N403','N404','N201']
```

Comment: What have you tried? And what error are you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `collections.Counter`:

```
In [38]: import collections 

In [39]: c = collections.Counter(l) # l is your data
```

Create a lookup of unique `<item: iter(range(count[item]))>`:

```
In [44]: lookup = {x : iter(range(c[x])) for x in set(l)}
```

Use list comp to return next count for that item:

```
In [45]: [x + str(next(lookup[x])) for x in l]
Out[45]: 
['N100',
 'N101',
 'N200',
 'N300',
 'N400',
 'N401',
 'N402',
 'N403',
 'N404',
 'N201']
```